# How use if from a value of a select JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this select form

```
<select id="measurement" name="measurement">
<option value="" selected>Select Measurement</option>
<option value="1" selected>Measurement 1</option>
<option value="2" selected>Measurement 2</option>
</select>
```

and I get its selection with this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#measurement').on('change', function () {
        var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        if (selected === 1) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Kostas/measurementData.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {UserID: <?php echo json_encode($UserID); ?>, MeasurementID: selected},
                success: function (data, selected) {
                   //some code

                },
                error: function (data) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

My if statement does not work, while the MeasurementID: selected passes the correct value when I remove the if, it isn't the same case with the if statement, it doesn't recognise it as 1 when it is. How do I do this right?

Comment: `val()` returns a string so use `== 1` or `=== '1'`. Closing as a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Rory McCrossan

> val() returns a string so use == 1 or === '1'